# Passing a special type of class as a parameter in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I'm writing a method to create a JLabel to store in a package so that I can use a method to create the JLabel instead of re-writing it every time in the future.

Right now I have

```
public static JLabel CreateJLabel(String nameOfLabel, String nameOfFont, int fontSize, int posX, int posY, SpringLayout layout, Frame frame) {
    JLabel myJLabel = new JLabel(nameOfLabel);
    Font myFont = new Font(nameOfFont, Font.BOLD,fontSize);
    myJLabel.setFont(myFont);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,myJLabel,posX, SpringLayout.WEST, frame);
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,myJLabel,posY, SpringLayout.NORTH, frame);
    frame.add(myJLabel);
    return myJLabel;
}
```

The specific area I'm looking at is

```
public static JLabel CreateJLabel(String nameOfFont, int fontSize) {
    Font myFont = new Font(nameOfFont, Font.BOLD,fontSize);
}
```

I'm wondering in the parameters of Font(), it takes the Font.BOLD to be specify the weight of the font, how do I write a parameter in the method so that the Font.BOLD is not hard coded but the user can type in a Font. style?

I tried

```
public static JLabel CreateJLabel(String nameOfFont, Font fontWeight, int fontSize) {
    Font myFont = new Font(nameOfFont, fontWeight ,fontSize);
}
```

but that didn't work, I also tried using an int type instead because it highlights as an int datatype in IntelliJ

```
public static JLabel CreateJLabel(String nameOfLabel, String nameOfFont, int fontWeight, int fontSize) {
    JLabel myJLabel = new JLabel(nameOfLabel);
    Font myFont = new Font(nameOfFont, Font.fontWeight ,fontSize);
}
```

[image]

But that was also an error.

Comment: *how do I write a parameter in the method so that the Font.BOLD is not hard coded but the user can type in a Font. style?*... you can use 2 `JCheckBox`es (one for `BOLD` and one for `ITALIC`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*I also tried using an int type instead*" - this is the correct approach, since `BOLD` is simply a `static int` constant of [`Font`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html), which you simply need to pass to your method. But your error is here:

```java
new Font(nameOfFont, Font.fontWeight, fontSize);
                         ^
```

This is incorrect java syntax.

What you actually want to do is to pass the int constant method parameter directly to the constructor of `Font`.
Since this constructor you try to use expects an int, you will simply have to pass the int itself like this for it to work as you expect:

```java
public static JLabel createJLabel(String labelContent, String nameOfFont, int fontWeight, int fontSize) {
    JLabel myJLabel = new JLabel(labelContent);
    Font myFont = new Font(nameOfFont, fontWeight, fontSize);
    myJLabel.setFont(myFont);
    // do other stuff
    return myLabel;
}
```

Finally, you can use your method to create the label as follows:

```java
JLabel myLabel = createJLabel("LabelContent", "Serif", Font.BOLD, 12);
```

An alternative (and probably better approach) would be to pass a `Font` object to your method directly, instead of passing all the parameters you need to create a `Font` object.

For example:

```java
public static JLabel createJLabel(String labelContent, Font myFont) {
    JLabel myJLabel = new JLabel(labelContent);
    myJLabel.setFont(myFont);
    // do other stuff
    return myLabel;
}
```

Calling it like this:

```java
JLabel myLabel = createJLabel("LabelContent", new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 12));
```

Sidenotes:

- `fontWeight` should be renamed to the a more correct variable naming like `fontStyle`.
- Method names should start lowercase. Therefore I renamed your `CreateJLabel` method to `createJLabel`.

Comment: Ah that worked, maybe I was just overcomplicating things haha. Thanks for the detailed answer.

And I always thought bold or not bold was considered font weight, I know in CSS it is, maybe it's different in Java

Comment: @jp1955 Haha, I probably was too pedantic to call out the parameter naming, but yes, the java [`Font`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#Font-java.lang.String-int-int-) calls this "style".